# Error with plotting knn classification accuracy rates using ggplot()

Tags: r

I have accuracy rates from a KNN classification from a training set as a vector:

```
> accs_1
[1] 1.0000000 0.8026316 0.7368421 0.7105263 0.6710526 0.6578947
[7] 0.6184211
```

And I have accuracy rates from a KNN classification with 5-fold cross validation:

```
> accs_2
[1] 0.6175000 0.5666667 0.6975000 0.5525000 0.5300000 0.5525000
[7] 0.5275000
```

The values of k are:

```
k <- c(1,3,5,6,9,11,13)
```

How can I plot a graph showing the accuracy rate over training set (accs_1) and the cross-validated accuracy rate (accs_2) for each value of 1/k?

Something similar to this:

[image]

I have been trying to do it with ggplot but I cannot figure it out. I used the following code:

```
all_accuracies <- c(accs_1, accs_2)

all_accuracies_as_data_frame <- as.data.frame(all_accuracies)


plot <- ggplot(all_accuracies_as_data_frame,aes(x = 1/k,y = accs_1, col = accs_2))+ geom_line(color = "blue") + 
  geom_line(aes(x = 1/k,y = accs_2, col = accs_2),color="orange")

plot
```

But it throws up errors:

```
Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (14): x and y
```

How can I plot this? Can I get some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `c(accs_1, accs_2)` they are combined into a single vector length 14 and so the resulting data.frame has 14 rows. Then there is a mismatch between the length of `all_accuracies_as_data_frame` and `k`. You should do the following instead:

```r
all_accuracies <- data.frame(accs_1, accs_2, k)
```

Then use `all_accuracies` in the call to `ggplot`.